# MaskRCNN anchors layer for Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to use MaskRCNN with Tensorflow 2.x. Here is the github link to the original code https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.
Originally they have use a Lambda layer to create a variable in Tensorflow 1.x:

```
anchors = self.get_anchors(config.IMAGE_SHAPE)
anchors = np.broadcast_to(anchors, (config.BATCH_SIZE,) + anchors.shape)
anchors = KL.Lambda(lambda x: tf.Variable(anchors), name="anchors")(input_image)
```

This is the function of get_anchors:

```
def get_anchors(self, image_shape):
        """Returns anchor pyramid for the given image size."""
        backbone_shapes = compute_backbone_shapes(self.config, image_shape)
        # Cache anchors and reuse if image shape is the same
        if not hasattr(self, "_anchor_cache"):
            self._anchor_cache = {}
        if not tuple(image_shape) in self._anchor_cache:
            # Generate Anchors
            a = utils.generate_pyramid_anchors(
                self.config.RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES,
                self.config.RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS,
                backbone_shapes,
                self.config.BACKBONE_STRIDES,
                self.config.RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE)
            # Keep a copy of the latest anchors in pixel coordinates because
            # it's used in inspect_model notebooks.
            # TODO: Remove this after the notebook are refactored to not use it
            self.anchors = a
            # Normalize coordinates
            self._anchor_cache[tuple(image_shape)] = utils.norm_boxes(a, image_shape[:2])
        return self._anchor_cache[tuple(image_shape)]
```

However, this is not feasible with Tensorflow 2.x so I found a workaround to create a subclass of Keras layer:

```
anchors = self.get_anchors(config.IMAGE_SHAPE)
anchors = np.broadcast_to(anchors, (config.BATCH_SIZE,) + anchors.shape)
class AnchorsLayer(KL.Layer):
        
        def __init__(self, anchors, name="anchors", **kwargs):
            super(AnchorsLayer, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
            self.anchors = tf.Variable(anchors)
    
        def call(self, dummy):
            return self.anchors
    
        def get_config(self):
            config = super(AnchorsLayer, self).get_config()
            return config

anchors = AnchorsLayer(anchors, name="anchors")(input_image)
```

I can run the code, but I noticed that when I do model.summary() the original layer has 0 parameters while the new layer has a lot of parameters. So my question is, where do these parameters come from and will this affect the model architecture and performance? And if it affect the model performance, how can I fix it? Thank you!!

[image: snippet of model summary from original code]

[image: snippet of model summary from new code]

Comment: What shape does `anchors` have ?

Comment: Hello, the output shape is (1, 261888, 4)

Comment: And what is the point of the AnchorsLayer, what should it do?

Comment: Hi, sorry but I am also not exactly sure since I am still new at deep learning and still learning MaskRCNN. But I believe the AnchorsLayer serves to wrap the variable anchors into a layer. Anchors are a set of boxes(maybe this is why there is a shape of 4 for coordinates) with predefined locations and scales relative to images. This is based on my understanding

Answer (score 0):

So I found a working repo for MaskRCNN with Tensorflow 2.0 https://github.com/ahmedfgad/Mask-RCNN-TF2. They used Keras instead of tensorflow.keras for the layers. So there are no problems with using the original Lambda layers for anchors